# Select proper records

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need help with this query:

```
SELECT Max(UQ.rcd_num) AS Max_RCD_NUM, 
       UQ.emp_id, 
       UQ.pperiod, 
       UQ.prun, 
       UQ.pc, 
       UQ.amount 
FROM   time1 AS UQ 
GROUP  BY UQ.emp_id, 
          UQ.pperiod, 
          UQ.prun, 
          UQ.pc, 
          UQ.amount;
```

it reads these data:
[image]

and it gaves me this result:
[image]

but I want for the red marked data to get only record with Max_RCD_NUM 9224, not Max_RCD_NUM 7972 in this particular sample.

This query is later used as a subquery for this query:

```
SELECT time1.* 
FROM   time1 
       INNER JOIN query3 AS TIMEAGG 
               ON ( [time1].[pperiod] = TIMEAGG.pperiod ) 
                  AND ( [time1].[prun] = TIMEAGG.prun ) 
                  AND ( [time1].[emp_id] = TIMEAGG.emp_id ) 
                  AND ( [time1].[pc] = TIMEAGG.pc ) 
                  AND ( [time1].[rcd_num] = TIMEAGG.max_rcd_num );
```

Can you please help me fix my first query so it would select only one record with highest Max_RCD_NUM for specific PPERIOD and specific EMP_ID?

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 you are missing the desire output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you need the record with the highest `Max_RCD_NUM` for specific `PPERIOD` and specific `EMP_ID` you only should group by `PPERIOD` and `EMP_ID`. In your example you could fix your query by simply remove the grouping criterion `amount` because it differs in the rows with Max_RCD_NUM 9224(amount=1725) and Max_RCD_NUM 7972 (amount=1840).

```
SELECT Max(UQ.rcd_num) AS Max_RCD_NUM, 
       UQ.emp_id, 
       UQ.pperiod, 
       UQ.prun, 
       UQ.pc
FROM   time1 AS UQ 
GROUP  BY UQ.emp_id, 
          UQ.pperiod, 
          UQ.prun, 
          UQ.pc;
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but when I tried that I got this error message "You tried to execute a query that does not include the specific expression 'amount' as part of an aggregate function."

Comment: My bad, of course you have to remove the `amount` from the listof selects as well. I edited my answer..

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery.  What you want to do is filtering, rather than aggregating:

```
SELECT uq.*
FROM time1 as uq
WHERE uq.RCD_NUM = (SELECT MAX(uq2.RCD_NUM)
                    FROM time1 as uq2
                    WHERE uq2.emp_id = uq.emp_id and uq2.pperiod = uq.pperiod
                   );
```

Comment: randomDude1001 - yes, your query now works fine and gave me the proper results. Thank you!

Comment: Gordon Linoff - thanks for your suggestion, but when I try to run your query it gives ma a prompt 'Enter Parameter Value uq2.Max_RCD_NUM'

Comment: @user10360284 . . . Your question states:  "only record with Max_RCD_NUM 9224".  Apparently, you are referring to *RCD_NUM*, not *Max_RCD_NUM*.